# What prevents one from replaying a BCC transaction by nulling the SIGHASH_FORKID bit?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, replay-attack

BCC transactions are "replay-protected" by the SIGHASH_FORKID 0x40.
However why can't I take one such transaction, flip off the 0x40 bit and here's a valid transaction on the BTC chain?

I guess that bit enters into the signature somewhere, but where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all the `sighashType` field with (or without) any bit fields is used in source data while for signing. The signature does not sign itself, but it signs `sighashType`. So, changing `sighashType` invalidates signature.

Second, the data for signature is created in different manner.